# Java Scanner in Loop only gets first input

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get multiple inputs from the user using a for loop. Within that loop I'm calling a function that includes a scanner. The program works fine when I call the function just once. But within a loop only the first time the function is called it works correctly. I've created a simplified example of the program below. How can I change this so the other iterations of the loop also work correctly?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String response = "";

    for(int inputNr = 0; inputNr <=2; inputNr++) {
        response = getResponse();
        System.out.println(response);
    }

}

public static String getResponse() {

    String response = "";

    System.out.println("Enter a String");

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(userInput.hasNextLine()) {
            response = userInput.nextLine();
        }
    userInput.close();

    return response;
}
}
```

The result looks like

```
Enter a String
This is what I entered...
This is what I entered...
Enter a String

Enter a String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the `Scanner` object which is linked to the standard input stream `System.in`. This causes `System.in` to close and therefore no more input is accepted. On the next iteration `userInput.hasNextLine()` returns `false`. Create a single instance of `Scanner` and close it after all iterations of the loop are run.

```
private static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String response = "";

    for (int inputNr = 0; inputNr <= 2; inputNr++) {
        response = getResponse();
        System.out.println(response);
    }

    userInput.close();
}

public static String getResponse() {

    String response = "";

    System.out.println("Enter a String");

    if (userInput.hasNextLine()) {
        response = userInput.nextLine();
    }

    return response;
}
```